# not able to set npm proxy

Tags: node.js, npm

I am completely new to set up NPM. I have executed the following commands. My password has special characters like **@ : #**. However I am not able to set the proxy. Is my password creating a problem?

```
npm config set https-proxy  "http://username:password@<servername>:<port>/"    
npm config set http-proxy  "http://username:password@:<servername>:<port>"   
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

Can some one help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a string jsut around your username and password and/or without http/https (and try you solution with your https proxy with and s too)

`npm config set https-proxy "username:password"@proxy.corp.com:PORT`